# ASP.NET MVC handle JsonResult in client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I want to return JsonResult from my controler

```
public JsonResult GetSubCategoties() {
        return Json(new { a = true, b = "testing" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is what i have on the client side:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Fragrance", "GetSubCategoties",
                            new AjaxOptions {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                OnComplete = "loadsubs"
                            })
```

and the function:

```
function loadsubs(result) {
//What should i do here?    
}
```

How do i handle the JsonResult in the client side?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadsubs(result) {
    alert('a = ' + result.a + ', b = ' + result.b);
}
```

Comment: i am looking for an infrastructure solution like result.get_response().get_object() in earlier versions of MVC

Comment: @uriz, if you are using unobtrusive jquery ajax then you could directly use `result.a`. If you use the obsolete MicrosoftAjax.js script you could retrieve the object using the following: `result.get_response().get_object().a` and `result.get_response().get_object().b`.

Comment: I am not using MicrosoftAjax and result.a is incorrect. look here: http://textsave.de/?p=104461 for the result content

Comment: @uriz, that's why you should use `result.get_response().get_object().a`. As far as the link you provided is concerned I don't understand anything from it.

Comment: those functions does not exist. where can i find their source?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "unobtrusive JavaScript" mode with jQuery, then the result should be your object.

Otherwise (and with ASP.NET MVC before V3), you can get the object like this:

```
var json = result.get_response().get_object();
```

Comment: i am using MVC 3/4 developer preview and those functions are not there

Comment: @uriz, as I wrote it depends on whether you use the old MS AJAX (which is also included but not required in ASP.NET 3) or the newer unobtrusive JavaScript with jQuery.

Comment: I am using the new unobtrusive JavaScript

Comment: @uriz, have you looked at the result variable content in the debugger (on the browser)? What's in there?

Comment: there are many fields the. I can do: var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result["responseText"]); and it will work. but i am looking for a tested function with error handling

Comment: @uriz, is there a `message` property?

Comment: look at this: http://textsave.de/?p=104461 its the entire JsonResult object that is being send to the client